# Python Selenium: Get headers from undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, undetected-chromedriver

How I can get the request headers from webdriven in undetected_chromedriver.v2?
The follow code not works with undetected_chromedriver:

```
driver.requests
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting CDP, then looking for `network.requestWillBeSentExtraInfo` - it's in the docs I think.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).